# Not getting a drop down menu for "img" in Gatsby / GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smHhNzM5Uo4).

I have trips.json in my data folder

```json
[
    {
        "img": "../assests/images/bahamas.jpg",
        "name": "Bahama Beach"
    },
    {
        "img": "../assests/images/china.jpg",
        "name": "Chinese Palace"
    },
    {
        "img": "../assests/images/dubai.jpg",
        "name": "dubai"
    },
    {
        "img": "../assests/images/monke.jpg",
        "name": "monke",
        "alt": "monke monke monke monke"
    }
]
```

Here is my gatsby-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `My Gatsby Project`,
    description: `Made with Gatsby.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    siteUrl: `https://gatsbystarterdefaultsource.gatsbyjs.io/`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `videos`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/videos`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
      options: {
        // Add any options here
        author: `me`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

At localhost:8000/__graphql, I am getting a checkbox for "img."

[image]

However, the tutorial makes extensive use of many properties within the "img" attribute.

I have tried to stop the process, do `gatsby clean` and restart the process.

So I want to figure out why I am not seeing this and how I can get this drop-down to appear on my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the following to `gatsby-node.js`

```js
exports.createResolvers = ({
  actions,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
  createResolvers,
  store,
  reporter,
}) => {
  const { createNode } = actions
  createResolvers({
    StrapiPageContentArticleGallery: {
      imageFile: {
        type: `File`,
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          return createRemoteFileNode({
            url: `${source.url}`, // for S3 upload. For local: `http://localhost:1337${source.url}`,
            store,
            cache,
            createNode,
            createNodeId,
            reporter,
          })
        },
      },
    },
  })
}
```